# How to connect windows service with UI configuration app?

Tags: c#, user-interface, service

I need to have a windows service that is configured with simple UI. I understand, that I need to create an API for windows service and use it in separate desktop application. But whatever I google I just got "you can't create UI to windows service" or info about webservice. 
 I found this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1159908/Yes-I-Know-But-I-Still-Want-a-GUI-for-my-Windows-S but this seems to be a pretty bad workaround, because I can't use already started service in my GUI using it. 
 What I need is some code, explaining how to create a connection between these two applications

Comment: Have both applications use the same database?

Comment: If all you need is to configure your service, did you think about a simple configuration file? Or even a sqlite database file, if your configuration gets too complicated? Your service would then just monitor the file and reload the parameters if it changes. That's way simpler than creating an API just to change a configuration

Comment: If you really want to avoid a configuration file though, the term you are searching for is IPC "inter-process communication"

Comment: There's no DB in application. What service does is sending requests to a web server, this server needs credentials. Customer wants to have simple tray UI where credentials are set